# Creating New GUID automatically while inserting a new row to an existing table Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing table in MS SQL called myTab.
It has the following fields

```
empno(PK) nchar(10),
 age int
```

Now, i want to add a myGUID column and fill it up with a GUID whenever i insert a new row as well as Updating existing rows.

So i added the statement

> ALTER TABLE myTab ADD myGUID uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NewId() NOT NULL;

Updating existing rows works correctly.

But, when i try to insert values,

> INSERT INTO myTab VALUES ( 1000, 22 );

It fails, and gives the following message

```
**Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**
```

When i do

> insert into sourav_test2 values (20055711,23,NEWID());

The above statement works.

I want a GUID to be filled without changing the insert statement. Is it possible via a Trigger or a Function?

Comment: When you do inserts without providing the fields you are inserting into you have to insert all fields.  So either way you have to update your insert statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sourav's question about triggers got me thinking, so I tried a little test.  Why?

Imagine a scenario where an application has already been written with thousands of INSERT statements that leave off the column list.  In this case, if you could write an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger that provides the column list, you could hopefully save yourself from correcting thousands of INSERT statements due to a newly added column.

Off the top of my head, I admittedly did not know if this could work.

So I wrote this little test:

```
CREATE TABLE tt (ColA varchar(1));

INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('a');

ALTER TABLE tt
ADD ColB uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWID();

GO

CREATE TRIGGER tr_tt
ON tt
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS 

INSERT INTO tt (ColA)
SELECT ColA FROM inserted;

GO

INSERT INTO tt VALUES ('a');

SELECT * FROM tt;

DROP TABLE tt;
```

I also tried a variation of the TRIGGER with the following INSERT just to be thorough:

```
INSERT INTO tt (ColA, ColB)
SELECT ColA, NEWID() FROM inserted;
```

The result was the same in both cases:   The same error as reported in the question.   So to answer the question:

> Can't we use a trigger here which can do it?

The answer is NO.   Even if you put an INSTEAD OF INSERT TRIGGER on the table, the parser will still not let you write an INSERT..VALUES() statement unless the number and order of VALUES exactly matches the definition of the table.  A TRIGGER cannot be used to get around it.

Sooner or later, lazy coding exacts its price.

Answer (score 6):

Always list the columns you are inserting!

```
INSERT INTO myTab (empno, age)
    VALUES ('1000', 22);
```

Also use correct types for the values.  Unmentioned columns will be assigned their default values, or `NULL` if there is no explicit default.

Your table has three columns, so if you leave out the column list, then the `insert` expects three values.  You can still set a default, if you want by using the `DEFAULT` keyword in the `VALUES` clause:

```
INSERT INTO myTab (empno, age, myGUID)
    VALUES ('1000', 22, DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Can't we use a trigger here which can do it?

Comment: @SouravDas . . . Huh?  A default value sets `myGUID` on insert.  A trigger is utterly unnecessary.